# How can i make the paths of my .desktop global?

Tags: python, shell, ubuntu, desktop

I have a `.desktop` app that runs a python code inside a shell script with double-click and it has it's own icon. (My Host is Ubuntu 18.04)
Here is my `.desktop` code:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=App
Type=Application 
Icon=/path/to/icon/icon.png
Exec=/path/to/script/sc.sh
```

The code of my shell script is the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
python3 path/to/file/python_script.py
```

and `python_script.py` code is:

```
from tkinter import *
import cv2

window = Tk()
window.title('Testing')
window.geometry('350x250')
label = Label(window, text="Python Script Test Successful! :)", fg="darkred")
label.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor=CENTER)
input("press any key to exit")
```

My goal is to change my paths that i have in my `.desktop` and and shell script to global instead of local, so that i can run them from another users PC. For example, if i sent it to Judy, she can run a copy of this script on her system, too.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [run python scripts from anywhere in the filesystem in windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27979436/run-python-scripts-from-anywhere-in-the-filesystem-in-windows)

Comment: @Karthik This mayy help in windows, however, i am Working on ubuntu